# custom string sorter

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I want to sort a collection by one of the properties which is a string, but i dont want to sort alphabetically.

Here is my code

```
 IEnumerable<Item> items = Repository.Query<Item>().OrderBy(r=> r.Status)
```

Status is a string but i want to sort in a particular order (not alphabetically)

how do i inject a custom sorter in the above syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Order by has an overload that takes `IComparer`.
Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422.aspx).